# How do I track, pull, etc. from an existing git branch on Github

Tags: git

I have the master branch from a repository on Github cloned on my machine. There are other existing branches in this repository that I would like to be able to switch to and use. I'm trying to use the command:

```
git branch --track nameOfBranch origin/nameOfBranch
```

This isn't working for me. I get the error:

```
error: the requested upstream branch (URL) does not exist
```

Basically I need to create the branch on my local machine and tie it to an existing branch. Thank you for your help!

Comment: what is the output of git branch -r

Comment: @user1281385 I see the master branch and one other branch that I have on there, but there are not any other branches that are in the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. To create a local tracking branch that you can work on the following should work.

First you need to clone the repository:

```
$ git clone git://thisismyrepo.com/project
$ cd project
```

Next find the branch you want to be working on:

```
$ git branch -a
```

That will output all the branches in your repo. Next you want to switch over to the branch you want to work on by:

```
$ git checkout origin/examplebranch
```

In order to work on that branch you can then do:

```
$ git checkout -b examplebranch origin/examplebranch
```

That should cause it to track and allow you to work on it as a local branch. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have cloned the repository but when I type "git branch -a" it is not showing all of the branches that are visible on Github. "git checkout origin/examplebranch" does create a new branch but it is tied to the master. The third command returns "fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'joinerr' at the same time." I wonder if something is wrong with the repository.

Comment: Is it a private repository that you are not willing to share, or can you post it here so I can attempt to clone it and test?

Comment: @bstrong Are you sure that you fully cloned the repo? What I said works perfectly for me. And I see your bstrong branch. What do you see when you type `$git branch -r`?

Comment: That must have been the problem. I re-cloned and it worked. Thank you very much!